# How to get value from a joiner table in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a joiner table that connects 2 tables, and stores some additional meta-information about the relationship. How can I get values from the joiner table, using either `dataset` or `model` methods?

For example:

```
class Artist < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :albums,
    left_key: :artist_id,
    right_key: :albums_id,
    join_table: :artists_albums
end

class Albums < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :albums,
    left_key: :album_id,
    right_key: :artist_id,
    join_table: :artists_albums
end
```

Joiner table contains an extra field, `authorship`, which signifies whether an artist was the primary author of the album, a collaborator, a guest appearance, etc:

```
CREATE TABLE `artists_albums` (`artist_id` integer, `album_id` integer, `authorship` varchar(255))
```

I'd like to get the artist's `authorship` value for a particular album:

```
artist = Artist[1]
album = artist.albums.first

# authorship = ???
```

Comment: You are using simple many-to-many relation. In rails there is a rich many-to-many association using `:through`

Comment: @zaingz, I'm not using Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default in Sequel is to only select from columns in the associated table, not columns in the join table.  You can use the `:select` option to specify a selection: `Artist.many_to_many :albums, :select=>[Sequel.expr(:albums).*, :authorship]`